# Error Loading Transformer

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, dart, angular-dart

**SOLUTION**

So there were actually two issues that I ran into when trying to build the application. The first was the transformer error. However, the comments to this post show how to fix this error (remove .pub-cache in home directory, remove .pub in project directory, and then run pub get, and pub cache repair).

However, the second issue that I ran into was that scissors has several external dependencies that I forgot existed. When I formatted my machine these dependencies were removed. Once I installed these I was able to build the project again.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Currently, I am running into an issue when running `pub build --mode=debug --verbose` where the angular2 transformer is not loading.

I formatted my machine last night and re-installed everything. Building worked fine before I formatted, however, now it is failing. So I have no idea what could be causing it.

I have tried removing .pub-cache and pulling back the dependencies. I have also tried running `pub cache rebuild --verbose` and nothing seems wrong / out of the ordinary. I am not sure what I am missing.

Below is the full output from the above command.

```
FINE: Pub 1.21.0
IO  : Deleting directory build.
FINE: Loading asset environment...
FINE: Initializing barback...
FINE: Serving packages on localhost:0.
MSG : Loading source assets...
FINE: Providing sources for test_project|lib.
FINE: Loading source assets finished (0.060s).
FINE: Provided sources.
FINE: Loading transformers...
FINE: Transformer dependencies:
    | scissors: -
    | angular2: -
    | dart_to_js_script_rewriter: -
    | chrome: -
FINE: Using cached transformer snapshot.
MSG : Loading scissors, angular2, dart_to_js_script_rewriter and chrome transformers...
FINE: Loading transformers from [scissors, angular2, dart_to_js_script_rewriter, chrome]
FINE: Spawning isolate from ./.pub/transformers/transformers.snapshot.
FINE: Loading scissors, angular2, dart_to_js_script_rewriter and chrome transformers finished (0.109s).
FINE: Transformers from scissors: {group of [[SassC]]}
ERR : Error on line 18, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer: Couldn't find library at package:angular2/transformer.dart.
    |     platform_directives:
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FINE: Exception type: TransformerLoadError
FINE: package:pub/src/barback/transformer_isolate.dart 126   TransformerIsolate.create.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             _Completer.completeError
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_isolate.dart 129   TransformerIsolate.create.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             _asyncErrorWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_isolate.dart       TransformerIsolate.create
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_loader.dart 72     TransformerLoader.transformersFor.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             Future.Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_loader.dart        TransformerLoader.transformersFor
    | dart:async                                             Future.wait
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 108                         waitAndPrintErrors
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_loader.dart 118    TransformerLoader.transformersForPhases.<async>.<fn>.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             Future.wait
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_loader.dart 117    TransformerLoader.transformersForPhases.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             Future.Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_loader.dart        TransformerLoader.transformersForPhases
    | package:pub/src/barback/load_all_transformers.dart 92  loadAllTransformers.<async>.<fn>.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             Future.wait
    | package:pub/src/barback/load_all_transformers.dart 90  loadAllTransformers.<async>
    | dart:async                                             _SyncCompleter.complete
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_loader.dart 61     TransformerLoader.load.<async>
    | dart:async                                             _SyncCompleter.complete
    | package:pub/src/barback/transformer_isolate.dart 81    TransformerIsolate.spawn.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/barback/load_all_transformers.dart     loadAllTransformers
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 503     AssetEnvironment._load.<fn>.<async>.<fn>.<async>.<fn>.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | package:pub                                            AssetEnvironment._load.<fn>.<async>.<fn>.<async>.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/log.dart 408                           progress
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 502     AssetEnvironment._load.<fn>.<async>.<fn>.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             Future.Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 662     AssetEnvironment._withStreamErrors
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 501     AssetEnvironment._load.<fn>.<async>
    | dart:async                                             _SyncCompleter.complete
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 663     AssetEnvironment._withStreamErrors.<fn>
    | dart:async                                             _SyncCompleter.complete
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 522     AssetEnvironment._provideSources.<async>
    | dart:async                                             _SyncCompleter.complete
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 521     AssetEnvironment._provideSources.<async>.<fn>.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart         AssetEnvironment._load.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/log.dart 408                           progress
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 450     AssetEnvironment._load
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 82      AssetEnvironment.create.<fn>.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             Future.Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart         AssetEnvironment.create.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/log.dart 408                           progress
    | package:pub/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 74      AssetEnvironment.create
    | package:pub/src/command/build.dart 65                  BuildCommand.onRunTransformerCommand.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                             Future.Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/command/build.dart                     BuildCommand.onRunTransformerCommand
    | package:pub/src/command/barback.dart 56                BarbackCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 177                   CommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                                             Future.Future.sync
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 130                   CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 128                PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>.<fn>
    | dart:async                                             Future.Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 72                          captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace                                    Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 86                          captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 128                PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>
    | dart:async                                             _SyncCompleter.complete
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 214                PubCommandRunner._validatePlatform.<async>
FINE: Wrapped exception: Couldn't find library at package:angular2/transformer.dart.
    | package:$pub/transformer_isolate.dart 86   _initialize
    | package:$pub/transformer_isolate.dart 28   loadTransformers.<fn>.<fn>
    | package:$pub/serialize.dart 159            respond.<fn>
    | dart:async/future.dart 168                 Future.Future.sync
    | package:$pub/serialize.dart 159            respond
    | package:$pub/transformer_isolate.dart 25   loadTransformers.<fn>
    | dart:async/zone.dart 1338                  _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded
    | dart:async/stream_impl.dart 331            _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
    | dart:async/stream_impl.dart 258            _BufferingStreamSubscription._add
    | dart:async/stream_controller.dart 768      _StreamController&&_SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData
    | dart:async/stream_controller.dart 635      _StreamController._add
    | dart:async/stream_controller.dart 581      _StreamController.add
    | dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 148  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
    | 
    | package:$pub/transformer_isolate.dart 86   _initialize
    | package:$pub/transformer_isolate.dart 28   loadTransformers.<fn>.<fn>
    | package:$pub/serialize.dart 159            respond.<fn>
    | dart:async/future.dart 168                 Future.Future.sync
    | package:$pub/serialize.dart 159            respond
    | package:$pub/transformer_isolate.dart 25   loadTransformers.<fn>
    | dart:async/zone.dart 1338                  _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded
    | dart:async/stream_impl.dart 331            _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
    | dart:async/stream_impl.dart 258            _BufferingStreamSubscription._add
    | dart:async/stream_controller.dart 768      _StreamController&&_SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData
    | dart:async/stream_controller.dart 635      _StreamController._add
    | dart:async/stream_controller.dart 581      _StreamController.add
    | dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 148  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
FINE: Transformers from dart_to_js_script_rewriter: {DartToJsScriptRewriter}
FINE: Transformers from chrome: {Chrome}
FINE: Loading transformers finished (0.673s).
FINE: Initializing barback finished (0.785s).
FINE: Loading asset environment finished (0.974s).
```

Here is the pubspec.yaml

```
name: temp_project
description: A Dart app that uses Angular 2
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.19.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: any
  chrome: any
  http: any
dev_dependencies:
  scissors: ^0.6.6
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
transformers:
- scissors:
    verbose: true
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
    resolved_identifiers:
      BrowserClient: 'package:http/browser_client.dart'
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
- chrome
```

Comment: How does the `pubspec.yaml` file look like? Especially the transformers part

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added the pubspec.yaml

Comment: Did you check what Angular2 version was actually fetched. Using `any` usually doesn't lead to the expected result.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it leads to 2.2.0 which is the version I expected. I tried using 2.1.0 as well with the same issue.

Comment: Did you check if the file (`packages/angular2/transformer.dart`) is actually there? Try to delete the `.pub` directory and run `pub cache clean`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So removing `.pub` and running `pub cache repair` again worked (`pub cache clean` didn't exist) and it fixed the error. However, now there is no error but it gets stuck on `Loading angular2 transformers...`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, `pub cache repair` is correct. Try killing `pub serve` from the `pub serve` view in WebStorm. Besides that I have no idea.